# PROLOG: Operator what is "-->"

Tags: prolog, operators, dcg

i am quite new to prolog and i'd like an explanation about something if possible.

What exactly does the

> "-->"

prolog operator do?
i can't seem to find an easy straight answer for that.

and just one more thing...

what's the difference between:

```
    phrase--> noun(X),
verb(X).
```

and this

```
phrase:- noun(X),
verb(X).
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Prolog supports a notation for Definite Clause Grammars. The `-->` is actually short hand for a more elaborate predicate. If you enter this:

```
foo --> noun(X), verb(X).
```

And then do a `listing`, you'll see something like this this:

```
foo(A, B) :-
   noun(X, A, D),
   verb(X, D, B).
```

See here, for example: [Grammars in Prolog](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~warren/xsbbook/node10.html)

The shorthand makes it easier to express grammars in Prolog more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It's used for syntax analysis. You should read [this paper about DCG in Prolog](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~warren/xsbbook/node10.html)